# Content Query webpart shows (blank) for Link List from parent site in SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, content-query-web-part, links-list

I have a list of careers links in my parent site (/Lists/careerslinks/AllItems.aspx).
[image: Careers list]

I need this list to be displayed in the parent site, and in the careers subsite, but when I create a Content Query webpart, and choose the above list, it displays the links as (blank), rather than with the description.

[image: Displaying as blank]

Answer (score 1):

Edit the web part>Presentation>scroll down to find "Fields to display" as shown below:

[image]

Fill in the desired column name in the correct text box.

In addition, I suggest you fill in the Title column as single line of text column rather than Hyperlink or Picture column, since it will show both link and description in the content query web part:

[image][image]

Comment: yeah, that was the big issue I was having! I wanted the link to display as the description of the link. The only time the (blank) went away was when I added URL [Custom Columns]; to Link, but then it showed up as the link and the description of the link together in one long line for each link. Your solution worked.

Comment: If the response is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.